# Trying to create a 4:1 Mux

Tags: verilog

```
module MUX_vector(
    input a,
    input b,
    input c,
    input d,
    input sel,
    output reg out
    );
    always@(a or b or c or d or sel)begin
        case(sel)
            2'b00 : out = a;
            2'b01 : out = b;
            2'b10 : out = c;
            2'b11 : out = d;
        endcase    
    end
    
endmodule
```

```
module MUX_vectortb;
    wire out;
    reg a;
    reg b;
    reg c;
    reg d;
    reg [1:0] sel;
   
    MUX_vector mux( .a(a), .b(b), .c(c), .d(d), .sel(sel), .out(out));
    initial begin
    #0 a = 4'h1; sel = 2'b00;
    #100 b = 4'h2; sel = 2'b01;
    #100 c = 4'h3; sel = 2'b10;
    #100 d = 4'h4; sel = 2'b11;
    #100 d = 4'h4; sel = 2'b11;
    $finish;
    end

    
endmodule
```

I think my design source is correct, but I'm not sure out to get my test bench to work.  Please let me know what to change. I think it might be something wrong with the initialization statements because, in the waveform graph, I see a lot of X's.

Answer (score 1):

There was an error on the mux model, the signal 'sel' needed to be a vector, it was a single bit.

Made a change to the always block to use always @(*), its easy to make a mistake listing signals individually.

```
    module MUX_vector(
        input a,
        input b,
        input c,
        input d,
        input  [1:0] sel,
        output reg out
        );
      always@(*)begin
            case(sel)
                2'b00 : out = a;
                2'b01 : out = b;
                2'b10 : out = c;
                2'b11 : out = d;
            endcase    
        end
    endmodule
```

For the testbench, the vectors were not written to demonstrate mux behavior.

The testbench was driving single bit signals with hex numbers such that  wrong thing was driven onto the single bits.

Added default values of 0, at t=0 for the inputs, so that the x's go away because you asked where the x's were coming from.

You might want to change the defaults to something meaningful.
Be aware the default of the types you have chosen is x.

Modified the testbench to demonstrate mux behavior.

```
module MUX_vectortb;
    wire out;
    reg a;
    reg b;
    reg c;
    reg d;
    reg [1:0] sel;
   
    MUX_vector mux( .a(a), .b(b), .c(c), .d(d), .sel(sel), .out(out));
    initial begin
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;

    #0 a   = 1'b1; sel = 2'b00;
    #50;
    a = 0;
      
    #100 b = 1'b1; sel = 2'b01;
    #50  b = 0;
      
    #100 c = 1'b1; sel = 2'b10;
    #50 c = 0;
      
    #100 d = 1'b1; sel = 2'b11;
    #50 d = 0 ;
      
    #50;
      
    $finish;
    end

endmodule
```